show only last names in biblatex fullcite and footfullcite
Is it possible to show only the last name of an author when showing citations with the biblatex \fullcite and \footfullcite commands?
For example, I'd like to suppress the first names of the authors in the following MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@book{doe2021,
  author    = {J. Doe},
  title     = {An Example Book},
  year      = {2021},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
}
@article{smith2020,
  author    = {Jane Smith},
  title     = {An Example Article},
  journal   = {Some Journal},
  year      = {2020},
  volume    = {10},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1-10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is a full citation: \fullcite{doe2021}.  
And here is a footnote citation: \footfullcite{smith2020}.
\end{document}


You may customise the two citation commands. Currently, this is their definition.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}} % This is the part to customise
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}} % This is the part to customise
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

You can change the options argument of the \usedriver{}{} command (that is the execution of the bibliography driver defined with \DeclareBibliographyDriver: see the package documentation, p. 332). So, try to write \DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname} instead of \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}.
Coming to a conclusion, try these two new definitions.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}} % Here the substitution
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}} % Here the substitution
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

I give you back the MWEB. I add also a bibliography list, to see that the \DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname} command is working only for the two customised citation commands.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@book{doe2021,
  author    = {J. Doe},
  title     = {An Example Book},
  year      = {2021},
  publisher = {Some Publisher}}
@article{smith2020,
  author    = {Jane Smith},
  title     = {An Example Article},
  journal   = {Some Journal},
  year      = {2020},
  volume    = {10},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1-10}}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}} % Here the substitution
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}} % Here the substitution
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is a full citation: \fullcite{doe2021}.  
And here is a footnote citation: \footfullcite{smith2020}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}

